# Producer and consumer functions for test thread-safe stack examples of C++ concurrency in action book

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, thread-safety

I've started to learn concurrency(C++11) reading the book C++ Concurrency in Action. How to test a thread-safe stack class (Example was taken from C++ concurrency in action listing 3.5). I would like to have differents implementations of producer/consumer functions that let me test all its functions.

```
#include <exception>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <stack>

struct empty_stack: std::exception
{
    const char* what() const throw();
};

template<typename T>
class threadsafe_stack
{
 private:
   std::stack<T> data;
   mutable std::mutex m;
 public:
   threadsafe_stack() {}
   threadsafe_stack(const threadsafe_stack& other)
   {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(other.m);
        data=other.data;
   }
   threadsafe_stack& operator = (const threadsafe_stack&) = delete;

   void push(T new_value)
   {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
       data.push(new_value);

   }

   std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
   {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
       if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
       std::shared_ptr<T> const res(std::make_shared<T>(data.top()));
       data.pop();
       return res;
   }

   void pop(T& value)
   {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        if (data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
        value = data.top();
        data.pop(); 
   }

   bool empty() const
   {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        return data.empty();
   }
};

int main()
{

  //test class 

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal testdriver for your structure could look like this:

```
struct Msg {
    size_t a;size_t b;size_t c;size_t d;
};

bool isCorrupted(const Msg& m) {
    return !(m.a == m.b && m.b == m.c && m.c == m.d);
}

int main()
{
    threadsafe_stack<Msg> stack;

    auto prod = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i){
            Msg m = { i, i, i, i };
            stack.push(m);
            //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1));
            if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                std::cout << "stack.push called " << i << " times " << std::endl;
            }
        }
    });

    auto cons = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i){
            try {
                Msg m;
                stack.pop(m);
                if (isCorrupted(m)) {
                    std::cout << i <<" ERROR: MESSAGE WAS CORRUPED:" << m.a << "-" << m.b << "-" << m.c << "-" << m.d << std::endl;
                }
                if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                    std::cout << "stack.pop called " << i << " times " << std::endl;
                }
            }
            catch (empty_stack e) {
                std::cout << i << " Stack was empty!" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    });

    prod.wait();
    cons.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

Note, that this doesn't test all different functions, nor for all possible race conditions, so you'd have to exend it.

Two recommendations regarding your class design:

1) I wouldn't throw an exception when the stack is empty, as this is a very common case in an asynchronous scenario. Rather make the consumer thread wait (see condition variables for this) or return a false or nullptr respectively.

2) Use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr<T>` in your  `pop()` function as it is more efficient and you don't share anything here anyway.

Comment: I got this error: /tmp/ccFEQ5CL.o: In function `empty_stack::empty_stack(empty_stack const&)':
listing-6.1.cpp:(.text._ZN11empty_stackC2ERKS_[_ZN11empty_stackC5ERKS_]+0x1d): undefined reference to `vtable for empty_stack'....

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to:

- Create a stack from your main function
- Start a thread that will fill the stack (pass the stack object pointer as parameter to the thread and make the thread execute a for loop filling the stack by calling push all the time)
- Then, while this thread runs, empty the stack from another loop of your main program

You can also declare the stack as a global variable if you simply want to do a quick test and don't know how to pass objects to the thread upon creation.

If you need clean exit, add an `atomic` (edited, I first recommended `volatile`) bool passed to the thread to tell it you're done and ask it to stop its loop. Then use join to wait for the thread to exit.

Comment: *a volatile bool*. why that? Why not reference to an atomic?

Comment: I'm not using c++11 yet....so I don't have acces to `std::atomic`. I'm often use volatile bool for safer thread access. But atomic seems to a good solution....I really have to move to c++11 standard!

Comment: erhm. the question was a genuine c++11 question ... `std::thread`, `std::mutex`, etc....

Comment: Please please don't use volatile. What volatile does is highly dependent on compiler flags, and as defined in the standard has nothing do do with threading. Multiple threads? Use `std::atomic`.

Comment: Could anyone put the best and eficient code that let me use this class? (It is just for learning reason)